# Getting count of something like keywords in patterns

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: finding instances of a string within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846753/c-finding-instances-of-a-string-within-a-string)

I want to get count of the 'if' keywords in an input , i have wrote this code,but not working at all

```
string pattern = "if" + "\\B";
```

also

```
string pattern = "\\B" + "if" + "\\B";
```

What pattern should am I use ?

Comment: Define "not working at all" - what _does_ it do? What is different from your expectation? Why did you choose this pattern?

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541954/how-would-you-count-occurences-of-a-string-within-a-string-c

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...

```
string sentence = "if abc if xyz"
string keyword = "if";
string pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(keyword) + @"\b";
int count = Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern).Count
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: there is no space between if and next word